# Noether-Lefschetz locus in enumerative geometry.

Tags: enumerative-geometry, ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

It is well known that if you have a smooth quartic surface $X\subset \mathbb{P}^3$, it may or may not have lines in it. Indeed, $X$ has the following options, 64 (the maximal number), 32, 16, or none.

Between the space of all such quartics in $\mathbb{P}^3$ which is $|\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(4)|=\mathbb{P}^{34}$, those with at least one line in it form a divisor $D$. Therefore, intersections of such a divisor with curves in $\mathbb{P}^{34}$ may give enumerative information about points(quartics) in the intersection.

Is all the enumerative information about such quartics encoded in $D$?

I'd like to know more about such a divisor $D$. So, Could someone recommend free-references of this online?

Comment: Do you want to restrict to smooth surfaces maybe?  Otherwise of course you can have more lines...  Also your question is a little vague.  What would "all the enumerative information" being "encoded" in D mean?  Is there a specific enumerative question you're interested in?

Comment: Sure, the smooth case, thks. On the other hand, what I meant is that a result in enumerative geometry may have an interpretation in terms of the "intersection theory" of such a divisor $D$.

Comment: I guess you know the article http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/arxiv/pdf/0705/0705.1653v2.pdf ?